# Are Dom, Doktor Mayhem, Matthew Read, and Community the only moderators on Music Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, moderators

When you reach 10,000 reputation, we can access to moderator tools.  However, only **Dom**, **Doktor Mayhem**, **Matthew Read**, and **Community** have a diamond moderator sign next to their names.  Are they the only moderators on Music Stack Exchange?

Comment: do not make trivial edits to bump your posts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes - that is the current moderator list. It can change over time: as sites grow, we run elections for more moderators, and if a moderator decides to step down we also run elections for replacements.

If you go to the Users page on any Stack Exchange site and click on the Moderators tab it will list all the moderators.

This sort of thing is all covered in the help pages - we have an extensive FAQ in there - it's worth a read. And the wider [Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) has everything!

Remember [**Community** is not really a moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user). It's a bot (robot) that does some low-level work for us but there's no person controlling it.

*There are a handful of people who have diamonds here that aren't moderators... but they all work for Stack Exchange.